# Symfony - How to create entity with a form and DTO

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dto

I want to create entity with symfony form and DTO. I tried to do DTO and form like I've seen on symfonycast. But there's something wrong and I can't figure it out.

After sending json file via postman I get an error:

Typed property App\Form\Model\CreateFacilityDTO::$pitchTypes must not be accessed before initialization (500 Internal Server Error)

postman body:

{
"name": "legia",
"pitchTypes": ["basketball"],
"address": "kosynierów"
}

Can You tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Facility;
use App\Form\CreateFacilityFormType;
use App\Form\Model\CreateFacilityDTO;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


/**
 * @method saveEntities(array $array)
 */
class CreateFacilityAction extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/create/facility", name="create_facility")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(CreateFacilityFormType::class);
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $form->submit($data);
//        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /** @var CreateFacilityDTO $facilityDto */
            $facilityDto = $form->getData();
            $createFacility = new Facility($facilityDto->name, $facilityDto->pitchTypes,
                $facilityDto->address);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($createFacility);
            $em->flush();
//            return new Response($data, 201);
//        }
        return new Response($createFacility, 201);

    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Form\Model\CreateFacilityDTO;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CreateFacilityFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('pitchTypes')
            ->add('address');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => CreateFacilityDTO::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
<?php


namespace App\Form\Model;


 class CreateFacilityDTO
{
    public string $name;

    public array $pitchTypes;

    public string $address;
}
```

Comment: public array $pitchTypes = []; Might get you past this particular error.  Might want to initialize the strings as well.

Comment: PHP thinks there is a  syntax error,  with the [ $name; ]  declaration. There is an unexpected 'string'  but PHP  expects a function or a const  in your code on line 9. It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local opsys.

Comment: @SuLlewellyn public string $name; is what is known as a typed property.  Typed properties were first introduced in 7.4 so older versions of PHP will indeed flag string as an error.  But it is actually perfectly valid and quite handy.